# How can I download packages to windows so that they can be installed in raspberry?

Tags: software-installation, packages

One thing I really dislike about Linux is the completelly obscure system of installing programs. It's really comfortable for normal user with access to internet, but not to me.

Whenever I want to install application on debian, I just find the package name on the internet and enter it in the shell.

My [raspberry is connected to my PC directly with crossover cable](http://pihw.wordpress.com/guides/direct-network-connection/). The one thing I really dislike about Windows is their obscure networking. It appears impossible to share my network connection to Raspberry. When I try to do so, all network configurations are reset.

This is why I was wondering, if I could download all the packages using some program on windows and then copy it to raspberry. Currently, I copy files to Raspberry using `wget` through which I access my local http server.

Is there a program to get a package and all the dependencies? Is there a program to install them on raspberry?

Comment: please, connect RPi to the network and install the packages the traditional way. trying to download them to windows will not bring you any happiness.

Comment: I can't. The network has mac address whitelist. And yes, it's horrible doing it that way. Sometimes I really wish for the internet to go down for a few days so that people start making applications that don't need it again.

Comment: bring it somewhere else, like home or to your friend's place, install the packages and bring it back.

Comment: This might take a week to happen. But your suggestions depict how desperate the situation is.

Comment: please, don't worry, we can wait. it's 2014 out there, and a computer without an internet connection is an anachronism.

Comment: Since mac addresses are being parsed by the operating system, not the network cards, you can try spoofing yours via the /etc/network/interfaces file by adding `hwaddress ether AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA` unterneath your `iface eth0 inet dhcp`.

Comment: Which OS are you using on the Pi?

Comment: Wheezy Raspbian. I have configured static IP address to both my notebook and Pi. Normal networking operations work (eg. `wget` to download files from PC's http server to raspberry).

Comment: only a guess: setup a http proxy on your pc and use the proxy on the pi...

Comment: That's what I'm doing right now. But I found that out after posting the question and it does not answer the original question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Installers work using packages on many Linux systems - Debian (Raspbian) uses `.deb` packages. So you can download the packages you need to install on your Pi, transfer them to the Pi and install them.

For instance, instead of running `sudo apt-get install iceweasel` (to install the Debian version of Firefox), you can:

- First, go to to [`https://www.debian.org/distrib/packages`](https://www.debian.org/distrib/packages#search_packages) and use the search tool to find the package you need (e.g. [iceweasel](https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/iceweasel)) - there is also a full (and very large) listing of the packages [here](https://packages.debian.org/stable/allpackages).
- You can then download the `.deb` package  - you will need to download the `arm` package linked at the bottom of the page (using the [`armhf`](https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/armhf/iceweasel/download) packages should work, `armel` might). Packages for other architectures won't work.
- Once on the Pi, you can install the package(s) by running

  > sudo dpkg -i */path/to/file/.deb /path/to/other/file.deb*
- If you end up with dependency problems *(extra packages are needed package you are installing to work)*, you should be able download those off of the Debian packages site as well. These dependency packages are listed on the package's page - e.g. for iceweasel, it says you need [xulrunner](https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/xulrunner-24.0)

---

**Edit:** just remembered another way would be to get `apt` on the Pi to give you the URLs of the files it needs instead of attempting to download the packages - so you would run the `apt` install command, but with `--print-uris` added in:

```
sudo apt-get --print-uris install PROGRAM
```

You can download the files from the URLs it gives on the Windows machine. The advantage of this is that it only prompts for the download of things it needs, and does required guessing as in my above answer.

I did an answer on this a while back [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/416982/178596) - it has some sample output and stuff.

Comment: By any chance, isn't there a script that that does make you a zip of all dependencies?

Comment: see the edit - surprised i forgot about this

Answer (score 0):

You really should fix your Internet Connection Sharing on your Windows computer.  Once that's working, then you'll fall in love with your Raspberry Pi again ;-)

In the mean time, you could investigate the [apt-offline](https://github.com/rickysarraf/apt-offline) package (assuming you're using a Debian based Pi distro).  It allows you to download packages to an USB stick for installing on an offline linux computer.  As it's a Python based application, then it works in Windows too.

Instructions for use are available [here](http://www.debian-administration.org/article/648/Offline_Package_Management_for_APT).  Although they are Linux based, you should be able to adapt them to work on Windows.

Comment: In fact, the problem resides in the Pi being unable to accept to shared connection for some reason. [I had problems using apt-offline on windows](http://superuser.com/questions/771044/how-to-make-apt-offline-on-windows) (though I thought python is platform independent).

Comment: I've added an answer to your apt-offline on Windows question.  What distro are you using on your Pi?

Comment: Wheezy raspbian (the most default thing for pi there is).